# Home and End key not working in neovim while it is working in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am having neovim and vim in my machine sharing same vimrc file.

When i press home and end key it works inside vim but not in neovim.

Neovim is installed using AppImage.

```
Vim version is : VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  9 2019 03:17:15)
NeovIm version is : NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.0.5
OS :Centos 7
```

I tried set term=xterm and set term=xterm-256color but it fails

E518: Unknown option: term=xterm-256color

echo $TERM returns xterm

How to enable home and end button in nvim?

Update:
There is a help document , :help $TERM

When i changed the term export TERM=putty-256color ,it works.
But i have to keep setting it many times . Need a way to set it in vimrc.

Comment: Which terminal are you currently using to start vim and nvim? Is it the same?

Comment: Yes same terminal i am using

Answer (score 1):

I use tmux and had `TERM` set to `xterm-256color`. It was fixed after setting it to `screen-256color`.

Source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6134

Comment: This fixed it for me too

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tmux config:

```
bind-key -n Home send Escape "OH"
bind-key -n End send Escape "OF"
```

source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6134#issuecomment-758475291